# What is wrong with my SQL file?

Tags: mysql, sql, dump

I downloaded the Stack Overflow data dump as XML files. Then I converted the XML files into SQL files. I tried to use the SQL file containing all the post data and import it to my MySQL database. However, when doing that, I get the following error message:

> RROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

I looked at my posts.sql file and I can't find a syntax error. Here are the first 30 lines of the posts.sql file:

```
insert into posts(Body, ViewCount, LastActivityDate, Title, LastEditorUserId, 
                    LastEditorDisplayName, LastEditDate, CommentCount, 
                    AnswerCount, AcceptedAnswerId, Score, CommunityOwnedDate, 
                    PostTypeId, OwnerUserId, Tags, CreationDate, FavoriteCount, Id) 
values 
(
    "<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form\'s opacity.</p>

    <p>This is my code:</p>

    <pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000;
    this.Opacity = trans;
    </code></pre>

    <p>When I try to build it, I get this error:</p>

    <blockquote>
      <p>Cannot implicitly convert type \'decimal\' to \'double\'.</p>
    </blockquote>

    <p>I tried making <strong>trans</strong> to <strong>double</strong>, but then the control doesn\'t work. This code has worked fine for me in VB.NET in the past. </p>", 
    "15207", 
    "2014-01-03T02:42:54.963", 
    "When setting a form\'s opacity should I use a decimal or double?", 
    "2648239", 
    "Rich B", 
    "2014-01-03T02:42:54.963", 
    "25", 
    "13", 
    "7", 
    "251", 
    "2012-10-31T16:42:47.213", 
    "1", 
    "8", 
    "<c#><winforms><forms><type-conversion><opacity>", 
    "2008-07-31T21:42:52.667", 
    "23", 
    "4",
);

insert into posts(Body, ViewCount, LastActivityDate, Title, LastEditorUserId, 
                    LastEditorDisplayName, LastEditDate, CommentCount, AnswerCount, 
                    AcceptedAnswerId, Score, PostTypeId, OwnerUserId, Tags, 
                    CreationDate, FavoriteCount, Id) 

values 
(
    "<p>I have an absolutely positioned <code>div</code> containing several children, one of which is a relatively positioned <code>div</code>. When I use a percentage-based width on the child <code>div</code>, it collapses to <code>0</code> width on IE7, but not on Firefox or Safari. </p>

    <p>If I use pixel width, it works. If the parent is relatively positioned, the percentage width on the child works. </p>

    <p>Is there something I\'m missing here? 
    Is there an easy fix for this besides the pixel-based width on the child? 
    Is there an area of the CSS specification that covers this?</p>", 
    "8524", 
    "2013-11-20T04:16:38.813", 
    "Why doesn\'t the percentage width child in absolutely positioned parent work", 
    "243557", 
    "Rich B", 
    "2013-10-04T01:14:10.373", 
    "12", 
    "5", 
    "31", 
    "121", 
    "1", 
    "9", 
    "<html><css><css3><internet-explorer-7>", 
    "2008-07-31T22:08:08.620", 
    "7", 
    "6",
);

insert into posts(Body, LastActivityDate, LastEditorUserId, PostTypeId, LastEditDate, 
                    CommentCount, Score, ParentId, OwnerUserId, CreationDate, Id) 

values (
    "<p>An explicit cast to double isn\'t necessary.</p>

    <pre><code>double trans = (double)trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;
    </code></pre>

    <p>Identifying the constant as <code>5000.0</code> (or as <code>5000d</code>) is sufficient:</p>

    <pre><code>double trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000.0;
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: SQL string delimiters are single quotes. So "this won't work as a string" 'but this will.'

Comment: Please [read the help on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). In particular, note that the editor has a helpful button to push to format selected blocks of code.

Comment: @catfood Only if ANSI_QUOTES is turned on in MySQL. By default, ["A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (“'”) or double quote (“"”) characters"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html). I'd agree it's good practice to use single quotes, but I don't think it's the problem here.

Comment: Consider reformatting this SQL

Comment: You have trailing commas after the values statements, the final select statement isn't even complete

Comment: @Tom Yes that's because I just posted the first 30 lines of the dump file.

Comment: Another good tactic when asking questions on Stack Overflow: Modify your example code to provide a much smaller and simpler and more readable demonstration of what the problem is. E.g., the size of that "BODY" value probably isn't relevant to your problem, so why not cut it down? E.g., since your reported error is on the first INSERT statement, go ahead and remove the others; they don't matter. And so on.

Comment: @catfood, but suppose the problem had been an unterminated quote inside the BODY. Sometimes it's necessary to see the full statement. But I agree that ideal questions should be asked with a *minimal* example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Then Fischer (OP) would have found the problem by noticing that before even posting the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You insert values list is incorrect(need to remove last comma)

```
... values("val", "val",)
```

fix it to:

```
... values("val", "val")
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the problem.